# How to put multi item object to each line of Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have an ArrayList of items that are linked to a custom Adapter. I would like my ListView to have a maximum of two, three or four items on each line of the ListView.

So multiple items would be on the same line of the ListView.

Is there a way to use the position variable within the custom Adapter class's getView() method to accomplish this?

Here is an example, sorry for the quality: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've faced such an issue before.

I've ended creating 2 adapters - one for handling vertical items, and horizontal adapter for handling items merge.

[image]

[Check my example](https://github.com/Yalantis/FlipViewPager.Draco/blob/master/flipviewpager/src/main/java/com/yalantis/flipviewpager/adapter/BaseFlipAdapter.java)